# How to filter column value by another column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

How to filter `Col2` value from `Col3` value. For example, I need to return only `Col2` value against `Col2` true value.

My data frame:

```
Col1            Col2                                   Col3 

Check           first,second,first,four,Five          true,true,false,true,false
```

Expected Data frame:

```
Col1            Col2                       

Check           first,second,four
```

Help me to achieve this, please.

dput,

```
structure(list(Col1 = "Check", Col2 = "first,second,first,four,Five", 
    col3 = "true,true,false,true,false"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "col3"))
```

Comment: In a `data.frame` all columns have equal length.

Comment: @snoram, No all column have different Length.

Comment: They have to have the same number of rows to be a `data.frame`. Please share your data using ´dput()`.

Comment: @snoram,please check dput above for Ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you present is very standard in `R` but the presentation of your data is not.

Your data seems more suited for a list, so I would start by transforming it into a list of vectors:

```
dlist <- lapply(lapply(df, strsplit, ","), unlist)
print(dlist)
$Col1
[1] "Check"

$Col2
[1] "first"  "second" "first"  "four"   "Five"  

$col3
[1] "true"  "true"  "false" "true"  "false"
```

Then it is easy to get it back into your expected outcome:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Col1 = dlist$Col1, 
                  Col2 = paste0(dlist$Col2[as.logical(dlist$col3)], collapse = ","))
print(df2)
   Col1              Col2
1 Check first,second,four
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation of your data.frame "db"

```
Col1<-c("Check","Check2")
Col2<-c("first,second,first,four,Five","first,second,first,four")
Col3<-c("true,true,false,true,false","false,true,false,true")

db<-as.data.frame(cbind(Col1,Col2,Col3))

    Col1                         Col2                       Col3
1  Check first,second,first,four,Five true,true,false,true,false
2 Check2      first,second,first,four      false,true,false,true
```

Filter Col2 by Col3

```
logical_value<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(db[,3]),","),as.logical)
list_Col2<-strsplit(as.character(db[,2]),",")

out<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(list_Col2))
{
  out[[i]]<-(unlist(list_Col2[i]))[unlist(logical_value[i])]
}
```

Output

```
out
[[1]]
[1] "first"  "second" "four"  

[[2]]
[1] "second" "four"
```

Comment: ,if i have more than 100 value means ,how i can do separated by Commas  by changing index value.

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple lines in the data.frame?

Comment: ,not like that if i have true ,false comma separation  more that 100 means how can i perform  as.character(db[,2]),",",as.character(db[,3]), etc

Comment: I changed the answer having a data.frame with multiple lines with different length of the value of Col2 and Col3